# Create base class of UIViewController with tableview and buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

I want to create base class of `UIViewController` with tableview for my App sharing functionality between two  almost similar `ViewControllers`.
When i Extend `UIViewController` with tableview did the child class get access to all views of its `superViewController` and all the  `(IBAction)undoAction:(id) sender`  methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that should work. If you subclass a UIViewController (or any other NSObject) you will be able to access all of its (public) methods. You can create a public method by defining them in the header file and adding an implementation of that method in the implementation file. These files will both be created while creating a cocoa (touch) class. The same thing applies to properties, the one you define in the header file will be accessible.

Let me know if you have any further questions